# How to get properties of a class in WinRT

Tags: c#, reflection, microsoft-metro, windows-runtime

I am writing a Windows 8 application in C# and XAML. I have a class with many properties of the same type that are set in the constructor the same way. Instead of writing and assignment for each of the properties by hand I want to get a list of all the properties of certain type on my class and set them all in a foreach.

In "normal" .NET I would write this

```
var properties = this.GetType().GetProperties();
foreach (var property in properties)
{
    if (property.PropertyType == typeof(Tuple<string,string>))
    property.SetValue(this, j.GetTuple(property.Name));
}
```

where `j` is a parameter of my constructor. In WinRT the `GetProperties()` does not exist. Intellisense for `this.GetType().` does not show anything useful I could use.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br230302.aspx#reflection

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You need to use [`GetRuntimeProperties`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/hh875138.aspx) instead of `GetProperties`:

```
var properties = this.GetType().GetRuntimeProperties();
// or, if you want only the properties declared in this class:
// var properties = this.GetType().GetTypeInfo().DeclaredProperties;
foreach (var property in properties)
{
    if (property.PropertyType == typeof(Tuple<string,string>))
    property.SetValue(this, j.GetTuple(property.Name));
}
```

Comment: Error: 'System.Type' does not contain a definition for 'GetTypeInfo'

Comment: It's an extension method, you need to import the `System.Reflection` namespace

Comment: After importing `System.Reflection` I get 'System.Reflection.TypeInfo' does not contain a definition for 'GetProperties'. Any other imports needed?

Comment: @IgorKulman, sorry, forgot about that... you can use either `GetRuntimeProperties()` (to get all properties, including the inherited ones) or `DeclaredProperties` (to get only properties declared by this type). See my edit

Comment: When reading the documentation (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/system.reflection.typeinfo.aspx), you have to ignore those items that don't have a green briefcase icon (Supported in .NET for Windows Store apps).

Comment: TypeInfo.GetRuntimeProperties isn't available for Windows RT, either. See Rico's answer below, it works like a charm.

Comment: @NickPruehs, [yes it is](http://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/hh875138.aspx). But it's an extension method, you need to import the System.Reflection namespace

Comment: My edit to make the code above compilable was rejected by respectable peers, so I just post it here. The first line should look like `this.GetType().GetRuntimeProperties()` to satisfy the compiler (`GetRuntimeProperties()` is an extension method for `Type`, not `TypeInfo`).

Comment: @Shaddix, your edit was correct, but incomplete, since the text still mentioned `TypeInfo` ;). The situation with `Type`/`TypeInfo` is a bit confusing, because in the full .NET framework, `TypeInfo` inherits from `Type` (so the code in my post compiled fine on this platform), but in WinRT it doesn't, so it didn't compile... To add to the confusion, the documentation doesn't mention the fact that `TypeInfo` inherits from `Type` in .NET 4.5... no idea why.

Comment: @Shaddix, more information [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dotnet/archive/2012/08/28/evolving-the-reflection-api.aspx). See the section "Compatibility across .NET target frameworks"

Answer (score 6):

Try this:

```
public static IEnumerable<PropertyInfo> GetAllProperties(this TypeInfo type)
{
    var list = type.DeclaredProperties.ToList();

    var subtype = type.BaseType;
    if (subtype != null)
        list.AddRange(subtype.GetTypeInfo().GetAllProperties());

    return list.ToArray();
}
```

and use it like this:

```
var props = obj.GetType().GetTypeInfo().GetAllProperties();
```

**Update:** Use this extension method only if `GetRuntimeProperties` is not available because `GetRuntimeProperties` does the same but is a built-in method.

Comment: I really hope this function could be added to `TypeInfo` class itself.