# Reflection in WinRt getting parameter of an inherited class

Tags: c#, inheritance, reflection, windows-runtime

I got two classes, and i want to use reflection.

```
public Class A
{
    public string aa { get; set; }
    public string bb { get; set; }
    ...
}

public Class B: A {}
```

when i try to get the Property of an B object i got no properties;

```
TypeInfo b = typeof(B).GetTypeInfo();
IEnumerable<PropertyInfo> pList = b.DeclaredProperties;
```

pList is always null, maybe because i used "DeclaredProperties" instead of GetProproperties(), but in winRt i can't use it.

i've read this solution [How to get properties of a class in WinRT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13197704/how-to-get-properties-of-a-class-in-winrt) but i can't use `var properties = this.GetType().GetTypeInfo().GetRuntimeProperties();`  because GetRuntimeProperties() is not recognized

> Solution Found, doubts still remain

To get the property of an inherited class i need to get the RuntimeProperties in this way

```
IEnumerable<PropertyInfo> pList = typeof(B).GetRuntimeProperties();
```

ignoring the PropertyInfo, and it works too if i try to get the property of an A object

What are the differences between `getType().GetTypeInfo()` and `getType().GetRuntimeProperties()` while i'm reading the property of an A object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public string aa;
public string bb;
```

These are not properties. Properties are defined such as:

```
public string Aa
{
    get;
    set;
}
```

For more information, look up [the official documentation on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x9fsa0sw.aspx).

Once you've made the corrections to your classes `A` and `B`, you will be able to use :

```
var classProperties = typeof(B).GetTypeInfo().DeclaredProperties;
```

For properties defined within the class B, and :

```
var allProperties = typeof(B).GetRuntimeProperties();
```

For properties that are defined within the class *and* in its inheritance tree; i.e. properties that are actually accessible at runtime (therefore the name of the method).

If you don't want to change the `public` fields to properties (but you definitely should), use the `GetRuntimeFields` method on `typeof(B)` and `DeclaredMembers` on `typeof(B).GetTypeInfo()` for similar behaviour.

Comment: "What are the differences between getType().GetTypeInfo() and getType().GetRuntimeProperties()" => those are two very different methods. If you are talking about the `DeclaredProperties` property on the `TypeInfo` class, I've already explained the difference between it and `GetRuntimeProperties`.




"Solution Found, doubts still remain" => if you have more questions about the subject, open another one ; if my answer solved your issue mark it as the answer.