# How to use reflection to get a static property of a class in WinRT

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, winrt-xaml

I can get a non-static property no problem ([How to get properties of a class in WinRT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13197704/how-to-get-properties-of-a-class-in-winrt)), or a static property in c# .net, but can't figure out how to get a static property in C3 winrt.

This is as far as I've gotten. Can anyone help?

```
            Type type = typeof(ToastNotificationManager);
            var typeInfo = type.GetTypeInfo();
            var historyProperty = type.GetRuntimeProperty("History");
            object history = historyProperty.get
            property.SetValue(obj, value);
```

I'm trying to reflect for and call ToastNotificationManager.History.Remove() which is only supported on the phone ([ToastNotificationManager.History](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows.ui.notifications.toastnotificationmanager.history.aspx))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works fine:

```
PropertyInfo propertyInfo =
    typeof(ToastNotificationManager).GetRuntimeProperty("History");

propertyInfo.SetValue(null, value);
```

Assuming, of course, that the `ToastNotificationManager` type *has* a property named `History`. :)

Note that when accessing static properties, you simply pass `null` as the object reference. Since there's no instance connected with a static member, obviously you don't need to pass a reference to one.